# Do I need to use a WeakReference for circular dependency?

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks, weak-references

We're talking **Android** here. We've modeled our architecture using **Model-View-Presenter** approach, and we hit an issue regarding **weak references**.

Quick Info:

- Presenter handles logic, network calls, etc.
- Views handles showing data on screen, displaying loading bars, etc.

The **Activity/Fragment** classes hold a reference to the **presenter**.
The **presenter** classes hold a reference to the **view** classes.

Our **view** clases are actually interfaces usually implemented by **Activity/Fragment**. This means a circular dependency between the `Activity/Fragment -> presenter` and `presenter -> view (an Activity/Fragment)`. For this reason, we made the `presenter` hold a **weak reference** to the `view (Activity/Fragment)`.

Today we needed to use 2 **views** in the same `Activity` (to display different model-data), so we didn't `implements` it on the `Activity` but created 2 anonymous class. This ended up in the `presenter` losing the `view`'s references (because it's a weak reference).

Now we're evaluating 2 posibilities:

1. We don't really need the `presenters` to hold a `WeakReference` on the `View` cause this type of circular dependency won't leak memory.
2. Instead of using anonymous classes, we hold a references on the `Activity` (so both presenter and activity have a reference to view) **just for the sake of it not getting deallocated** (which feels smelly).

Which one is it, do we need the presenter to hold the view as a weak reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is 1 - you don't need a WeakReference in the presenter in this case. I'm using the same pattern successfully. No memory leaks occur - when the activity gets GCed the presenter goes with it. But there might be other types of problems - if you keep somewhere (for example in AsyncTask) hard reference to the presenter.

Answer (score 2):

As Galya already pointed, you don't need `WeakReference` for on `Presenter` because it will be destroyed when `Activity` destroyed. But if I right understand your problem, you try to "fix" MVP pattern. Maybe a [VIPER](https://cheesecakelabs.com/blog/using-viper-architecture-android/) pattern could help you?